# ADFS - Claims - emailAddress urn format version mismatch

Tags: saml, windows-server, windows-server-2016, adfs3.0

So I was setting up an ADFS service on a Windows Server 2016 instance. I created a Relying Party Trust, and was about to create 2 claim issuance policies since our Service Provider has a nameId policy which needs to be met. The required policy is as follows

```
<NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:emailAddress" AllowCreate="true"/>
```

So I added these two claims:

[image]

The second is a transformation rule as follows:

[image]

This resolves to the rule language:

`c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"]
 => issue(Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", Issuer = c.Issuer, OriginalIssuer = c.OriginalIssuer, Value = c.Value, ValueType = c.ValueType, Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/format"] = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress");`

The problem is, that this generates a format of `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress` and not `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:emailAddress` as in the requested policy and seemingly I can't change it to SAML2.0 as I can not manually edit the rule. Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: Since I couldn't fix this, I just removed the NameID policy on the SP side so there is no restriction on the NameID format

Answer (score 0):

Copy that rule and use it to make a new custom policy rule and then edit it.